# Every time I walk my zipper falls HELP ME

Tags: bathroom

I can’t keep my zipper up every single time I walk it 3 people  have pointed it out to me plz help me

Comment: How many different pairs of pants that you own have this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible reasons for this issue:

- Physical: The zipper does not have a [locking feature](https://www.ykkfastening.com/products/zipper/s_zipper.html). Zipper sliders may have various types of self-locking features, such as a small prong on the pull-tab that engages the elements (*teeth*) when the tab is in the close position. Perhaps the lock on one or more garments is broken. The remedy is to [replace the slider or the whole zipper](https://www.manmadediy.com/2698-the-diy-tailor-three-common-broken-zipper-problems-and-how-to-fix-them).
- Psychological: For some reason, you're forgetting to close the zipper. Perhaps a simple reminder, such as putting a small burr on the pull tab that you'd feel when unzipping, could help you remember.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

"Fly won't stay up? Attach a key ring to the zipper and hang it over the button."
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dHYY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The very end of your zipper pull has a tiny hole. Use a safety pin through that hole and the cloth of the zipper to hold your zipper closed.

You can also use a safety pin through the zipper horizontally below the zipper-pull to prevent it from moving past the pin.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a collar and a string. Attach the string to the collar at one end and the zipper at the other. Make sure that when you hold your arm out, the string is taunt and pulls the zipper up.
As you walk, the zipper is pulled taunt by the natural swaying of your arms.

[image: collar, string arrangement]